# Can't Run JAR Files

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I can run my project through netbeans but after I make a jar file and double click it I get the error cannot find Java runtime environment? I am on Windows.

Comment: How do you have the JRE installed? When you open a Command Prompt, what happens when you run "java" ?

Comment: I added the "windows" tag, since the question is not really about java, but about running java on windows.  It might be relevant which kind of windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a file associate created.  Right click on the .jar file in Internet Explorer, select Open With, and navigate to your JRE.  Select the java.exe executable, and make sure the command-line argument has ' -jar ' present.

The .jar file will be passed as the first argument to the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have JRE installed.
Open the console and type `java -version`

Answer (score 1):

You should download a Java runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might try, as Chris said, making sure the JRE executable is part of your PATH environment variable. Check out "4. Update the PATH variable (Optional)" from [this guide](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/jdk/install-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JRE bin dir is in your PATH env variable.

Comment: You should add the JDK not JRE to your PATH

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the Manifest - http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans run the project.  It will ask you what class to run (you will see a list of all the classes with a "public static void main(String[])" method).  Once you do that the next time you build the class netbeans will show you how to run it (with the -jar witch).  Now you should be able to double click on it.