# Unable to run .jar files by double-clicking them on Windows 7

Tags: java, jar, javaw

Running a .jar file in the command line works fine, but **I am unable to execute .jar files on my PC by double-clicking them**. What is interesting, the same .jar files successfully execute on my laptop with a double-click.

I included `%JAVA_HOME\bin` and `JDK_HOME\bin` in the `PATH` variable.
I have `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121`.
I have `JDK_HOME`   set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`.

For some period of time, the *Java(TM) Platform SE binary* disappeared from the `Open with` list, and I could not add it until I changed the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jar_auto_file\shell\open\command` key in `regedit.exe` to the appropriate version:

> *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_**121**\bin\javaw.exe" "%1".*

Here is a snapshot of Windows CMD with `java -version` entered on my PC:
[image: java -version in Windows CMD]

**I tried the following methods, with no success:**

- reinstalling both JRE and JDK,
- associating .jar files with `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe`,
- using `assoc .jar=jarfile` and `ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` in command line,
- creating a new system Environment Variable **OPENDS_JAVA_ARGS** and setting it to *-jar*.

**Additional information:**

- I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (Service Pack 1) with latest
  updates installed both on my PC and laptop.
- Running .jar files by double-clicking them **used to work** on my PC,
  but suddently stopped working some time ago. I did not modify
  anything related to Java.
- I have the newest version of both JRE and JDK (Java 8 version 121).
- Of the .jar files I am trying to run, some are GUI Swing applications
  and some open the system console (if not already open) using
  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])`.

**I have already tried fixing this problem with solutions on the following links (without success):**

- [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)
- [How to open/run .jar file (double-click not working)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966394/how-to-open-run-jar-file-double-click-not-working)
- [I can run .jar files through cmd, but I cannot double click them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434292/i-can-run-jar-files-through-cmd-but-i-cannot-double-click-them)
- [Can't Run JAR Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724892/cant-run-jar-files)

**Notes:**

- I do not want to open .jar files with WinRAR.
- I do not want to open .jar files by running `java -jar jarfile.jar` in cmd.exe.
- I am not looking for a 3rd party application to run .jar files.

*For now, I am using `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "java -jar C:\path\to\jarfile\Program.jar"` as a shortcut location to run jar files, but I am not satisfied with this solution as this opens the console to run even Swing applications.*

Comment: That's a well-written question, you put a lot of work into it. Yet I fear it might get flagged as off-topic as it is more of a general hardware/software issue than a programming question. Just so you're aware.

Comment: Then I should consider creating an account on superuser and asking the same question there, if it does get flagged before anyone answers it.

Comment: You can use your stackoverflow account there, no need to create new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get *Java(TM) Platform SE binary* `(javaw.exe)` in the *Open with* list by matching paths in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry entries:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jar_auto_file\shell\open\command
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command

Seems like one of the entries pointed to an older version of Java. Now `.jar` files are finally showing icons, **but still do not work on double-click**.

### UPDATE: SOLUTION

Delete the `.jar` and `jar_auto_file` entries from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes` and it should work. `.jar` files should open on double-click again. 
Make sure to **backup these entries first** by right-clicking the entry and choosing `Export`.

*Additional information can be found on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1194758/unable-to-run-jar-files-by-double-clicking-them-on-windows-7/1211085#1211085).*